# I think a have problems with namespaces in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I have this problem.

My output look like this:

```
  <job id="">
      <str name="person or company">text</str>
      <str name="content">
         <content>
            <str name="title">
               <h1 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">text</h1>
            </str>
            <str name="detail">
               <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">text</p>
            </str>
```

And my namespeces look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:etl="http://etl.dob.sk/etl"
                extension-element-prefixes="str exsl"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml"
                etl:norefetch="1">
<!-- sys -->
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" cdata-section-elements="param url"/>
```

If i put this line to namespaces:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml7
```

then I have problem here:

```
 <job xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="">
      <str name="person or company">text</str>
      <str name="content">
         <content>
            <str name="title">
               <h1>text</h1>
            </str>
            <str name="detail">
               <p>text</p>
            </str>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: problem is <job xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your input elements are in the XHTML namespace and you copy them to the output unchanged but want to remove the namespace. So you need to change your code that copies the XHTML input elements to transform them e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

will strip the namespace and then instead of

```
<xsl:copy-of select="xhtml:h1"/>
```

you need

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml:h1"/>
```

You will need to share more of your stylesheet code if that does not help.